# How to use portion of image as a background for a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, java-platform-module-system

I'm creating a jigsaw app where the user needs to match a jigsaw piece to the missing one in the jigsaw itself.

What I have done at the moment is create an image object which holds the complete jigsaw image. Then I overlaid a jigsaw outline on top of it as another image. I then made a row of buttons on the bottom row of the jigsaw which together spell a word. One of the buttons get randomly coloured black to indicate it's a missing piece. The user then needs to pick the correct jigsaw piece with the correct missing letter of the word. My question is, how can I set the background of the missing jigsaw piece to the portion of the image that is missing/greyed out? Hope this made any sense?

Comment: Hey guys, would be great to hear any suggestions you may have :)

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use SpriteMask with a sprite that has the jigsaw shape.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html

Comment: Oh waw that sounds interesting! How would I reference to the position of the image where the jigsaw piece is missing? i.e. how can I extract the portion of background to form the background of a button?

Comment: Do you think @axis that I could somehow use a portion of the main image in separate buttons? Something like extracting the part of the image which is where the missing piece is and then applying it to be the background of a few buttons....?

Comment: If you know the position of the missing piece, you can use a copy of the full image and have the SpriteMark be at the same positon of the missing piece (which will make it so that you only see the missing piece portion of the full image).